# How to specify the range 'in:' argument of Swift 3 method range(of:options:in)

Tags: swift3

Trying to use the method like this:

```
let myrange = 0...3
let rang = data.range(of: data, options: NSData.SearchOptions(), in: myrange)
```

Get the following error.

```
cannot convert value of type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>' to expected argument type 'Range<Data.Index>?'
```

Documentation for method here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410391-range

specifies type for argument in: as NSRange. 
However creating an NSRange like this:

```
let myNSRange = NSRange(location: 3, length: 2)
```

results in this error:

```
cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected argument type 'Range<Data.Index>?'
```

How do I create a '`Range<Data.Index>`'that will work here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a `Range<Data.Index>` literally you have to use the `CountableRange` operator and annotate the type:

```
let data = Data(0..<100)
let subData = Data(0..<2)

let myrange : Range<Data.Index> = 0..<4
let rang = data.range(of: subData, in: myrange) // Range(0..<2)
```

Foundation `NSRange` and Swift `Range` are two completely different things.

By the way: The `options` parameter has a default value of *no options* and can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solved it completely and was the starting point to learn a whole lot about ranges under Swift 3.